# Previous data displayed when pushing new view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a strange navigation issue occurring in my Ionic 3 / Angular 2 app.  I am attempting to communicate between 2 components (pages) and the parent pushes the child component to the top of the stack:

```
goToCheckIn(client, i) {
    let that = this;

    this.callback = function(params) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        that.handleApproval(params['index'], params['approval'], true)
        res()
      })
    }

    console.log(client)

    this.navCtrl.push(CheckInApprovalPage, {
      client: client,
      index: i,
      callback: this.callback
    })
  }
```

I implemented a callback to allow the `nav.pop()` in the child to pass params to the parent [as seen in this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-navcontroller-pop-with-params/58104).  After performing its job, the child component pops off, passing data to the parent:

```
rateCheckIn(approval) {
    let updated = Object.assign({}, this.client.check_in)

    this.checkInService.update(updated).subscribe(
      success => {
        this.clientService.hideLoader()
        this.callback({index: this.index, approval: approval}).then(() => this.navCtrl.pop({animate: false}))

      }
    )
  }
```

Finally, the callback causes the parent to push the same child view, only with a new `client` object.

```
handleApproval(index, approval, from_callback = false) {

    let clients = _.slice(this.clients, index)
    let unsolved = _.filter(clients, [ "check_in['approved']", null ])
    let i = index + 1

    if ( unsolved ) {
      i = _.findIndex(this.clients, {id: unsolved[0]['id']})
    }

    if ( this.clients[ i ] ) {
      this.navCtrl.push(CheckInApprovalPage, {
        client: this.clients[ i ],
        index: i,
        callback: this.callback
      })
    }
  }
```

At this point, the child view appears with the correct `client` data for about 0.5s, and then reverts to the previous `client` data.  When I log `this.client` in the child (even after several second timeout), it displays the NEW `client`, but the view still shows the previous `client` data.  Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, quick question - what stopped you to use a canonical recommended way to pass data from child that "pops" to parent? why would you do a work around like the one you linked?

Comment: Basically if you could describe particular UX you are trying to achieve I am sure this should be solvable in multiple different ways without the need to do these tricks

Comment: @SergeyRudenko there is no way to pass params directly while "popping" in Ionic.  I could subscribe to an `event` and `publish` an event in `rateCheckIn()` but I ran into different problems doing it that way

Comment: I ended up solving it using a service.  I guess that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes sorry, in this type of case you consider a service that glues components together. Glad you solved it